# Node.js module error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been struggling last week with error handling, especially error handling in Node.js modules. So first, here is my code:

**user.js route**

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var newUser = new User({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err)
        } else if(user) {
            res.status(403).send('User already exists');
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    });
});
```

**user.js module**

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, cb) {
  User.findOne({ email: newUser.email }, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
      cb(err);
    } else if(user) {
      cb(null, user);
    } else {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if(err) {
          cb(err);
        } else {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) {
              cb(err)
            } else {
              newUser.password = hash;

              newUser.save(function(err, newUser) {
                if(err) {
                  cb(err);
                } else {
                  cb(null, false);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Everytime if there is error inside **user.js module**, call callback function and handle error inside **user.js route**. This works, but that mess inside my module doesn't look good, because there is so many if-else statements..

Is there better approach, or do I have to check everytime if there is error?

Comment: You can try using Promises to simplify the error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code to something like:

```
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, cb) {
  User.findOne({ email: newUser.email }, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
      cb(err);
      return;
    } 

    if(user) {
      cb(null, user);
      return ;
    } 

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if(err) {
        cb(err);
        return;
      } 

      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if(err) {
          cb(err)
          return;
        } 

        newUser.password = hash;

        newUser.save(function(err, newUser) {
          if(err) {
            cb(err);
            return;
          } 

          cb(null, false);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

However, if I were you and as @Scimonster stated in his comment, this is a typical use case for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) that would allow you to write more readable code and avoid the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)